# In ReactJS opening pdf in a new tab triggers browser's popup warning

Tags: reactjs

An image is being shown. On clicking the image a pdf file should open in a new tab. This is how I am trying to render the React component, doesn't work -

```
<a href={pdfUrl} target="_blank">
  <img className="class-image" src={imageUrl} onError={imgError}/>
</a>
```

When the image is clicked Chrome gives a warning that a pop-up has been blocked. Safari doesn't even give any warning and just eats the tab which it thinks is a pop-up.

I tried removing the `onError` attribute with no effect.

If I remove the `target="_blank"` attribute it works fine, opens the pdf in same window.

I have tried adding `onClick` handler to the `<a>` tag, opening a window using `window.open` with the same result - generates warning that a pop-up has been blocked.

This works fine however -

```
<a className="class-name" href={pdfUrl} target="_blank">{userName}</a>
```

The problem occurs if rather than rendering text as the content of anchor tag I render an image. Can't figure it out.

**EDIT:**

I got it to work like this -

```
<img className="class-image" src={imageUrl} onError={imgError} onClick={() => {functionThatOpensWindow()} }/>
```

1. Add an `onClick` handler to the `img` tag
2. Update the image class to change the pointer to a cursor so that it looks like a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work like this -

```
<img className="class-image" src={imageUrl} onError={imgError} onClick={() => {functionThatOpensWindow()} }/>
```

1. Add an onClick handler to the `img` tag
2. Update the image class to
   change the pointer to a cursor so that it looks like a link

Comment: Adding to this, here is what the function could look like to do this: `functionThatOpensWindow(url) { window.open(url, "_blank"); }`

Answer (score 1):

One approach that might work with this is to open the new window, then populate the URL:

```
const newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.location.href = '/some/url';
```